# Launching custom URL scheme in Flutter

Tags: facebook, flutter, instagram

I'm trying to implement [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories) functionality in Flutter. The android side is easy to mimic using the [android_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) package, however I've yet to find a way of launching custom URL schemes in Flutter. There are packages that allow custom URL schemes to be accepted in the app, however I don't think they can be used in my case ([uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links)).

I'm aware that I could use platform channels however I would prefer to keep my code all in Dart. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I use [firebase_dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) to handle custom URL schemes. You may want to consider also looking into that. You won't be needing to touch platform-specific code, but you'll need to update the AndroidManifest.xml and Info.plist file.